# selenium webdriver tab not switching

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

selenium webdriver tab swithching not working .

code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get('https://www.google.com')
 driver.implicitly_wait(2)


 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
 driver.get('http://www.rediff.com')


 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
 driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')

 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

In the last line if i change the index from [0] to [1] or [2] there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Use Keys to have the browser go back to the tab you want. If you want to jump to tab 1 use: driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + '1')